# Create an int[] from an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, casting, arraylist

Is there an easy way of creating an `int[]` or the equivalent `Integer[]` from an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

When I try `(Integer[])list.getArray()`, I get this stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;

The only other way I can think of is:

```
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++){
    array[i] = list.get(i);
    //or I could do list.remove(0), is there any difference?
}
return array;
```

but that way *seems* terribly slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yourIntList.toArray(new Integer[yourIntList.size()]);
```